# remove PRIMARY KEY from existing table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table with some PRIMARY KEY.
And I need to ad one more field which should be new PRIMARY KEY.
I am try to do next:

```
ALTER TABLE some_table
    ALTER COLUMN user_count DROP PRIMARY KEY,
    ADD COLUMN id serial PRIMARY KEY;
```

but I am getting next error:

```
Error: pq: syntax error at or near "PRIMARY"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, remove the primary key

```sql
ALTER TABLE some_table DROP CONSTRAINT user_count
```

Then add your new one

```sql
ALTER TABLE some_table ADD COLUMN id serial PRIMARY KEY
```

Comment: Error: pq: constraint "user_count" of relation "some_table" does not exist

Comment: Well you need to get the proper primary key name, I can't know it

Comment: it is proper name

Comment: Either the key or the table name is wrong, as the error message suggests. try `user_count_pkey`

Comment: https://dataedo.com/kb/query/postgresql/list-all-primary-keys-and-their-columns